# undefined method 'has_selector?' for rspec decorators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have the following rspec test:

```
# spec/decorators/user_decorator_spec.rb    
require File.expand_path 'spec/spec_helper'

describe UserDecorator do
  let(:user) { UserDecorator.new build(:user, level: build(:level)) }
  subject { user }

  its(:avatar) { should have_selector 'h6' }
end
```

and I get error:

```
Failure/Error: its(:avatar) { should have_selector 'h6' }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `has_selector?' for #<ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer:0x007fecbb2de650>
     # ./spec/decorators/user_decorator_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have tried the popular suggestion with:

```
before { ApplicationController.new.set_current_view_context }
```

but then it says `undefined method set_current_view_context`. I'm using `rspec 2.14.1` and `capybara 2.0.1`. Also, the strangest thing - when I wrote this test in some helper spec it passed, no problems...

Help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't feel very satisfied about using the `type: :view` solution proposed in this thread, despite it's a very valid one. The thing is that my spec file for a file inside `lib/` directory shouldn't be actually considered as a view spec.

So I did some further research over the internet and found out one that seems a better approach to me.

So considering the original example in this thread. You should just add the following line inside your describe block:

```
include Webrat::Matchers
```

So the final example would look like:

```
# spec/decorators/user_decorator_spec.rb    
require File.expand_path 'spec/spec_helper'

describe UserDecorator do
  include Webrat::Matchers

  let(:user) { UserDecorator.new build(:user, level: build(:level)) }
  subject { user }

  its(:avatar) { should have_selector 'h6' }
end
```

Comment: Although decorators do relate to views, your approach is more.. versatile, which probably makes it better.. ;). Thanks for sharing and for the time you spent on research.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest fix is probably to add `type: 'helper'` or `` `type: 'view' `` to your describe block:

```
describe UserDecorator, type: 'helper' do
  let(:user) { UserDecorator.new build(:user, level: build(:level)) }
  subject { user }

  its(:avatar) { should have_selector 'h6' }
end
```

Doing so will mix [`ActionView::TestCase::Behavior`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/TestCase/Behavior.html) and [`Capybara::RSpecMatchers`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/Capybara.md) in to your test.

Specs in your `specs/helpers` directory automatically get the `'helper'` type, and specs in `specs/views` automatically get the `'view'` type.

Since `specs/decorators` is a custom directory that isn't understood by `rspec-rails`, you need to [configure the type manually](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/directory-structure).

See [the RSpec Rails README](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/README.md) for more information on the types of tests it supports.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Still prefer write `have_selector` than the following regex: `/<(h6)>.*<\/\1>/`. One adjustment, `type: :view`, helper did not fly, beacuse decorator is a class and that was no bueno for rails/rspec.

Answer (score 1):

`has_selector` or its alias `have_selector` is the method of Capybara, not Rspec.

You are using plain Rspec here, so these methods are not possible.

You can use a simple REGEX to check that:

```
its(:avatar) { should match(/h6.*img/ }
```

Comment: Well, I do `require 'capybara/rspec'` in `spec_helper`, to my knowledge that should solve the problem. And as I said i did wrote this test in some_helper_spec.rb and it passes. I do realize that I can do some workaround, but don't quite get why exactly I do need to... if that makes sense..

Comment: I have not done that before as this is not the right use case of Capybara. Decorator, and/or helpers often need lightweight tests only, or no tests at all. Testing view is also rare in such tests. Also, require Capybara doesn't help, as the subject is not Capybara's page instance.

Comment: Well, probably you are right. However, the way I see it, is that I have method, that generates some html and I write a test in each view which uses it, or just test that method.

Comment: I understand. It's okay to test html code if it is important, but there should be no need of heavy usage. Anyway you can't use Capybara syntax here. If you do need heavy usage of selector, there is a gem for it, you can search that. But I think in normal cases some simple REGEX could do the job good enough.