# Using have_selector against a String object in Rails + RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm writing a spec upon a file inside lib/ directory.
And one of my methods in there returns a HTML string, but then I try something like:

```
expect(subject).to have_selector("p:eq(1)") do |first_p|
```

And it gives me the following error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(subject).to have_selector("p:eq(1)") do |first_p|
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `has_selector?' for #<String:0x007f93798a8338>
```

How can I work around this? Should I wrap the string object with some another specific object? I've tried with **Nokogiri::HTML.fragment()** but it didn't work out neither. I suppose I should wrap it with some webrat's object or something like that, but I don't know how to get there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the solution over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609043/undefined-method-has-selector-for-rspec-decorators#comment30881536_20621240 -- I've update the original question with the answer.

Comment: I removed my (old) solution from the question itself and posted a better one as an answer to this question thread. It now feels like the  right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't feel very satisfied about using the `type: :view` solution that I discovered earlier in this thread, despite it's a very valid one. The thing is that my spec for a file inside `lib/` directory shouldn't be actually considered as a view spec.

So I did some further research over the internet and found out one that seems a better approach to me.

So considering the original example in this thread. You should just add the following line inside your describe block:

```
include Webrat::Matchers
```

So the final example would look like:

```
describe MyApp::UI::MyDecoratorClass do
  include Webrat::Matchers
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Capybara to get the `has_selector?` method, you'll want to wrap your result in `Capybara.string(...)` to get access to the `has_selector?` method.

So your test should go from:

```
expect(subject).to have_selector("p:eq(1)")
```

To:

```
result = Capybara.string(subject)
expect(result).to have_selector("p:eq(1)")
```

Documentation: http://rdoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara#string-class_method

Comment: This would be a good solution if my app stack was including Capybara among my loaded gems. We're not using it at this point.

Comment: I've just found a good solution, Chris, check out the other answer.